# Which lifecycle callbacks are called when quick settings menu is opened?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, settings

Hi i have an (Main) activity which hosts (Match) fragment. I want to get notified when quick settings menu is opened. On MatchFragment i tried to overwrite methods as `onStop(),onResume(),onPause()` and in MainActivity i did the same. I put logs in every callback to see which of them is being called when user opens quick settings menu from the top but none of them got called.

So my question is how to check if upper quick settings menu was opened? Thanks

Comment: Override all and add some logs, then check your logcat.

Comment: Could you solve this? To me it looks as if the active activity is not informed at all, as if lifecycle is not influenced by opening/closing quick settings. But I want to update the UI according to the state changed by the quick settings tile.

Comment: Hi, i was unable to resolve it. I remember that i overrided all callbacks but none of them was called when menu was opened or closed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any callback methods for when the quick settings dropdown menu is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139878/are-there-any-callback-methods-for-when-the-quick-settings-dropdown-menu-is-open)