# Are there any callback methods for when the quick settings dropdown menu is opened?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

When I pull down the quick settings drop down menu while my app is opened and in the foreground, are there any callback methods called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a few quicks tests and [Activity.onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)) might work for you.  It fires when I drag down quick settings but it will also likely fire for other reasons, like AlertDialogs.

> **onWindowFocusChanged**
>
> void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
>
> Called when the current Window of the activity
>   gains or loses focus. This is the best indicator of whether this
>   activity is visible to the user.

Comment: Thank you. Can you confirm that onResume is not being called? Because that is not the case for me.

Comment: onPause/onResume does not fire when I open and close quick settings.