# Android API 29 Bluetooth configuration change is not calling onResume()

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm noticing that whenever I turn on/off bluetooth from swiping down, `onResume()` on the lifecycle does not get fired. Is this a bug or am I configuring something wrong?

Comment: Do you mean your activity doesn't go through onPause -> onResume when you swipe down to access Quick Settings and then swipe up to dismiss it?

Comment: @clownba0t exactly the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any callback methods for when the quick settings dropdown menu is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139878/are-there-any-callback-methods-for-when-the-quick-settings-dropdown-menu-is-open)